# Create Facebook Session Object using access token on Android

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-android-sdk

I am trying the following:

1. On one android mobile, I am authorizing my App with Facebook, and storing the access token in shared preferences.
2. Sending this access token to second android device (with some different app having same appKey for Facebook.
3. Now I am not able to create a Session using this access token on second device. The second device has no UI hence I can not use web/FB native app to authorize there.

Question: My question is how can I create a facebook Session to access APIs, using this passed access token. It will be more helpful if someone can point to an example.

Answer (score 2):

As of facebook sdk for Android 3.0 final, the api has changed and the answer suggested by @rightparen would not work. In the new API, the key is to use **`Session.openActiveSessionWithAccessToken()`** static method. This method is designed for the migration from fb sdk 2.x to 3.x .

The following code works for me.

```
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public static void migrateFbTokenToSession() {
    Facebook facebook = Utils.getFacebookObject();
    AccessToken accessToken = AccessToken.createFromExistingAccessToken(facebook.getAccessToken(), new Date(facebook.getAccessExpires()),
            new Date(facebook.getLastAccessUpdate()), AccessTokenSource.FACEBOOK_APPLICATION_NATIVE, Arrays.asList(Constants.FB_APP_PERMISSIONS));
    Session.openActiveSessionWithAccessToken(ICheezApplication.getContext(), accessToken , new Session.StatusCallback() {

        @Override
        public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
            sLogger.debug("fbshare Migration to newer icheez state has been successful");
            if(session != null && session.isOpened()) {
                Session.setActiveSession(session);
            }
        }
    });

}
```

Answer (score 1):

This function can migrate your existing token state by overwriting the default sdk cached token state with the parameters you pass in:

```
private final void migrateToken(String accessToken, long expiresMilliseconds,
                                List<String> permissions, boolean isSSO,
                                long lastRefreshMilliseconds) {
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    TokenCache.putToken(bundle, accessToken);
    TokenCache.putExpirationMilliseconds(bundle, expiresMilliseconds);
    TokenCache.putPermissions(bundle, permissions);
    TokenCache.putLastRefreshMilliseconds(bundle, lastRefreshMilliseconds);
    TokenCache.putIsSSO(bundle, isSSO);

    SharedPreferencesTokenCache cache = new SharedPreferencesTokenCache(this);
    cache.save(bundle);
}
```

If you don't have permissions saved, you should just pass the list of permissions you requested when you got the token or an empty ArrayList if you did not ask for any or do not know.

The isSSO parameter specifies whether you got the token using Facebook Login / SSO with the facebook app (true), or the login WebView (false).  Tokens obtained via Facebook Login can be extended, and this boolean controls whether the SDK should automatically attempt to extend the token.

This function overwrites the state that is read by the Session constructor.  So if you call the function, you will need to construct a Session afterwards to use it.  The logic might look like:

```
    Session session = Session.openActiveSession(this);
    if ((session == null) && hasOldTokenState()) {
        migrateToken(...);
        session = Session.openActiveSession(this);
    }
    // if session is still null, user will have to log in...
```

Comment: This does TokenCache API has changed in facebook3.0sdk final release. This method does not work as is anymore.

Comment: Now there is explicit support for this scenario.  You can use AccessToken token = AccessToken.createFromExistingAccessToken(accessToken, expiresDate, lastRefreshDate, AccessTokenSource, permissions); and then session.open(token, callback); or Session.openActiveSessionWithAccessToken(context, token, callback).

Answer (score 0):

Not know how to get that access token and Authorize the user but I am using below code to re create the Session if the Session is not valid.

```
private SessionListener mSessionListener = new SessionListener();

Utility.mFacebook = new Facebook(APP_ID);
Utility.mAsyncRunner = new AsyncFacebookRunner(Utility.mFacebook);
SessionStore.restore(Utility.mFacebook, getApplicationContext());

SessionEvents.addAuthListener(mSessionListener);
SessionEvents.addLogoutListener(mSessionListener);
```

My SessionEvent Class is:

public class SessionEvents {

```
private static LinkedList<AuthListener> mAuthListeners = new LinkedList<AuthListener>();
private static LinkedList<LogoutListener> mLogoutListeners = new LinkedList<LogoutListener>();

/**
 * Associate the given listener with this Facebook object. The listener's
 * callback interface will be invoked when authentication events occur.
 * 
 * @param listener
 *            The callback object for notifying the application when auth
 *            events happen.
 */
public static void addAuthListener(AuthListener listener) {
    mAuthListeners.add(listener);
}

/**
 * Remove the given listener from the list of those that will be notified
 * when authentication events occur.
 * 
 * @param listener
 *            The callback object for notifying the application when auth
 *            events happen.
 */
public static void removeAuthListener(AuthListener listener) {
    mAuthListeners.remove(listener);
}

/**
 * Associate the given listener with this Facebook object. The listener's
 * callback interface will be invoked when logout occurs.
 * 
 * @param listener
 *            The callback object for notifying the application when log out
 *            starts and finishes.
 */
public static void addLogoutListener(LogoutListener listener) {
    mLogoutListeners.add(listener);
}

/**
 * Remove the given listener from the list of those that will be notified
 * when logout occurs.
 * 
 * @param listener
 *            The callback object for notifying the application when log out
 *            starts and finishes.
 */
public static void removeLogoutListener(LogoutListener listener) {
    mLogoutListeners.remove(listener);
}

public static void onLoginSuccess() {
    for (AuthListener listener : mAuthListeners) {
        listener.onAuthSucceed();
    }
}

public static void onLoginError(String error) {
    for (AuthListener listener : mAuthListeners) {
        listener.onAuthFail(error);
    }
}

public static void onLogoutBegin() {
    for (LogoutListener l : mLogoutListeners) {
        l.onLogoutBegin();
    }
}

public static void onLogoutFinish() {
    for (LogoutListener l : mLogoutListeners) {
        l.onLogoutFinish();
    }
}

/**
 * Callback interface for authorization events.
 */
public static interface AuthListener {

    /**
     * Called when a auth flow completes successfully and a valid OAuth
     * Token was received. Executed by the thread that initiated the
     * authentication. API requests can now be made.
     */
    public void onAuthSucceed();

    /**
     * Called when a login completes unsuccessfully with an error.
     * 
     * Executed by the thread that initiated the authentication.
     */
    public void onAuthFail(String error);
}

/**
 * Callback interface for logout events.
 */
public static interface LogoutListener {
    /**
     * Called when logout begins, before session is invalidated. Last chance
     * to make an API call. Executed by the thread that initiated the
     * logout.
     */
    public void onLogoutBegin();

    /**
     * Called when the session information has been cleared. UI should be
     * updated to reflect logged-out state.
     * 
     * Executed by the thread that initiated the logout.
     */
    public void onLogoutFinish();
}
```

}

May be it will help you.

Comment: You are using Facebook class in your code, as per the documentation of Facebook class at the link below this class is kind of deprecated / not recommended, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/android/3.0/Facebook

Comment: @SpcFbone: ok fine. I am talking about what i am using before and help me a lot. Might be helpful to you.

Comment: [1] In your code it seems that you are not using stored access token to create a session?                             [2] I am trying sample named hackbook given in the FB's latest Android SDK "facebook-android-sdk-3.0.b"... This app also used similar concept, but the problem is that on each startup of the application it ask for a login in FB account. So did you also face the similar issue or any workaround for that?

Comment: No i am not facing such issue. Once if i login with the Facebook it will never ask me again till i signout from the facebook or remove application and reinstall it again.

Comment: I am using the same thing (Hackbook of facebook) for login and it works great. In extra if there is no session valid then i am using above code to regenerate the session of facebook.